# Which install-folder should I delete after installing Umbraco 7.4.3

Tags: installation, umbraco7

According to the [umbraco installation guide](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget) it is highly recommended that you delete the "install"-folder to prevent it from being accidently deployed to production.

I have installed Umbraco as a NuGet Package in Visual Studio but there are 3 install folders that I can find; one in the "Umbraco" folder, one in "Umbraco\Views" and one in "App_Data\Temp". Can someone tell me which one I should delete, or maybe all of them?

Answer (score 1):

After the installation is complete you only need to delete the `install` folder which is located under the `umbraco` folder.

This contains the contents of the installation process.

The install folder under `umbraco/Views` only contains the html of the installation process.

You can remove this also but its not neccessary.

If you look in the install folder under `App_Data/TEMP` then this will be empty after the installation is completed.

You can remove this also but again its not neccessary.

Comment: No, don't delete that folder. There used to be an install folder in the root of the install, but that no longer exists in Umbraco 7. I've removed this note from the documentation, there's nothing to remove.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out. Now I have to reupload this folder to all of my projects.

Comment: @sebastiaan I think your comment deserves to be made into an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete only install folder in the root. Another install folders should be removed automatically. Basically on latest Umbraco versions even root install folder is removing while install proces.